# Grafana displaying incomplete data from query results from BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, grafana

I'm connected to BigQuery from Grafana, and I'm getting wildly different results from queries compared to the BigQuery console and other query tools I've connected to BigQuery. Simple things like `select * from table` yield very different results. Grafana is returning 1400 records from a `select *` on a table with 4 million records. Anyone seen this before or have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in the `Query options`, the default value for `Max data points` is limiting the number of results to 1369. Set it to a higher number and the query will return that number of rows (it is used as `LIMIT` value in the query sent to the BigQuery API).